# Only one reference to <content></content> in polymer element?

Tags: dart-polymer

The boildown of the construct, is like this. Having a polymer element:

```
<dom-module id="demo-element">
  <template>
     <span><content></content></span>
     <span><content></content></span>
   </template>
</dom-module>
```

This only gives one occurrence of content. e.g.
`<demo-element>Hello</demo-element>` only gives "Hello" and not "HelloHello". Using a property with binding, gives the expected. Seems like some small detail missing, anyone who have been in similar parts?

```
Environment:
 Dart version 1.14.0
 WebStorm 11.0.3

From pubspec.yaml:
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.15
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  polymer_elements: 1.0.0-rc.8
  browser: ^0.10.0
  reflectable: ^0.5.0
  polymer_interop: ^1.0.0-rc.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. `<content>` doesn't produce elements, it just projects them.

More than one `<content>` without a selector doesn't do anything. The first one "grabs" all children and projects them where it is placed.

You can have more than one `<content>` tag but then they should have different selectors like

```
<header-elem>
  <content select=".header"></content>
</header-elem>
<drawer-elem>
  <content select=".drawer"></content>
</drawer-elem>
<body-elem>
  <content></content>
</body-elem>
```

used like

```
<my-component>
  <div>body</div>
  <div class"header">header</div>
  <div class"drawer">header</div>
</my-component>
```

then the first `<div>` is projected to the last `<content>` element because it doesn't match any specific selector, the other divs are projected to the `<content>` tags with the matching selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this clears up things. Great.